# MySql won't allow adding values in table -> ERROR 1054

Tags: mysql, sql, database, terminal

I have just created two tables in mysql and I cannot add anything into the tables in the form of values.

I have created them in the past using the same method and it has worked.

```
 mysql> CREATE TABLE customer_id
 -> (
 -> FirstName varchar(255),
 -> LastName varchar(255),
 -> Email varchar(255),
 -> Address varchar(255),
 -> PostCode varchar(255),
 -> Phone varchar(255));
 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

 mysql> show tables;
 +--------------------+
 | Tables_in_banglawf |
 +--------------------+
 | customer_id        |
 | music_categories   |
 | music_recordings   |
 | music_tracks       |
 | pizzas             |
 +--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show tables;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_banglawf |
+--------------------+
| customer_id        |
| music_categories   |
| music_recordings   |
| music_tracks       |
| pizzas             |
+--------------------+ 
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from customer_id;
Empty set (0.03 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO customer_id values(test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'test1' in 'field list'
mysql> INSERT INTO customer_id values(test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'test1' in 'field list'
```

Answer (score 2):

use `single quotes` for `varchar` data in values list else it will be parsed as `column's`

```
INSERT INTO customer_id (col1,col2,..col6)
 values('test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6');
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your values in single quotes, like this:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO customer_id values('test1','test2','test3','test4','test5','test6');
```

Otherwise, they are treated as column names since they are alpha (non-numeric) characters.